# How does X11 forwarding work?

Tags: ssh, x11, gpu

How does X11 forwarding work? I am interested in knowing whether the processing to render graphics is done at the end of the host running the application or the host displaying the graphical interface?

Should I use a GPU intensive application (game) - where should I have the GPU installed (server end / client end)? Of course the server will need the GPU if it is running CUDA / openCL applications, but what about the display?

---

[This question was closed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168720/how-does-x11-forwarding-work). [This](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168445-X11-forwarding-and-OpenGL-extensions) was a link pointed to me, but I am looking to understand more of the underlying protocol and performance tweaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX), the GPU should be installed on the host where the X server is running.  The client will send rendering commands to the X server, which will then take advantage of the GPU to process the rendering commands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a little more complex (and messy). Maybe the calculations of the game's graphics will be done on the server side (although the proper use of the GPU/OpenGL is not that clear, but everything about the interface is definitely calculated on the client side.

This post explains it pretty well:

https://superuser.com/questions/1217280/why-is-x11-forwarding-so-inefficient